# Why was this question migrated to Anime and Manga?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

This question was recently migrated to Anime and Manga

[Story-telling technique where the drawing style briefly gets much simpler?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/44496/1587)

however i am not sure why is was migrated to the

> question and answer site for enthusiastic anime and manga fans.

like the first web comic sorta looks like manga however it is to my understanding that we don't accept stuff just because it's "looks" like anime and/or manga. i am not familiar with Questionable Content but looking at the [about page](http://www.questionablecontent.net/about.php) all it says is

> Questionable Content is an internet comic strip about romance and robots. It started on August 1, 2003. It updates five times a week, Monday through Friday.
>
> Jeph Jacques writes and draws Questionable Content. It has been his full-time job since September 2004. Jeph is originally from Rockville, MD, USA and currently lives in Halifax, NS, Canada. Jeph also makes Alice Grove, which is a sci-fi comic strip. He is also currently doing dord.horse. He also makes music.

so it wasn't created in Asia (as we also deal with questions about Korean Manga called Manwha and Chinese Manga) or says it was inspired by anime or manga (like Avatar and RWBY). Jeph's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeph_Jacques) also doesn't mention anything mention anything about anime/manga or japanese.

So i am wondering why the question was migrated to Anime and Manga when it seems to not be about Anime and Manga at all?

Answer (score 2):

I migrated it because the author flagged a request to have it moved.  Based on the content of the post and when the author felt he would get a better answer on the site and I also thought it might receive a better answer, too.

If that is a fluke or if it's not within your scope or you dont think he would get the best answer there you can reject the migration.  However, even if I didn't migrate it the author would have just deleted it and asked so I was just trying to make it easier for the user.

Comment: Thank you for the move, and as the OP I still believe it was appropriate. One question: the comments disappeared during the move, which makes some sense, but there was information in there that I'd like to access. Is there a way I can see the comments that had accumulated? If only you can see them, then I'm looking for the Anime term that someone suggested might apply to my question. (Thanks again.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom reactivated the comments on [GD.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104801/story-telling-technique-where-the-drawing-style-briefly-gets-much-simpler)'s side.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but the relevant comments, which were on the question itself, seem to have been lost. No worries.